# How to sort one table has many relationship with another table in Rails 4?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have three table vendors, comments, works table.
I have to sort all vendors by no. of (admin_verified : true) reviews. If 'n' vendors have same number of review count, then sort by no of works count.

I wrote one active record query but it take only vendors if vendor have at least one verified reviews.
QUERY:

```
Vendor.
joins(:reviews).
where("reviews.verified"=>true).
group("reviews.vendor_id").
order("count(reviews.vendor_id)")
```

this query is between two tables only.
How to write rails active record query to sort vendors based on above order?

```
# vendor.rb
has_many :reviews
has_many :works

# review.rb (table_fields: 'verified','comment',... and so on)
belongs_to :vendor

# work.rb (table_fields: 'work_title','work_description',... and so on)
belongs_to :vendor
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
vendors = Vendor.joins('LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, vendor_id FROM reviews WHERE reviews.verified = 1) as r ON r.vendor_id=vendors.id')
              .joins('LEFT JOIN works ON works.vendor_id=vendors.id')
              .group('vendors.id')
              .select('vendors.* , COUNT(DISTINCT r.id) AS no_reviews, COUNT(DISTINCT works.id) AS no_works')
              .order('no_reviews DESC, no_works DESC')
```

In this case you can also access the counts from the vendor objects, e.g.: `vendors.first.no_reviews`

Comment: Thanks in advance! But the above active record query sort only the verified reviews vendor. I want to sort all vendors based on reviews. If vendor have no review, then it'll be last. For the above query, give only the vendor have reviews and it's verified.

Comment: @GoldenKing edited the answer. I misread the question. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to optimize this query?

Comment: @GoldenKing I don't see a trivial way to do that. I guess you could just introduce a bit of redundancy and store these counts on the `vendors` table too. You can easily keep them in sync with callbacks.